# Beginner question on Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I am new to PHP and am doing some research on Drupal system to set up a website for my church.
Just want to know how to development a module on a page that display a list of articles? eg. display the article by category or tag etc.

Is there any template I can use or I will need to develop the template myself?

Thanks in advance!

Chris

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [views module](http://drupal.org/project/views). It lets you define your own rules for viewing articles (or other content types), by tag, category, or any arbitrary conditions you can think of.

Answer (score 1):

in complement to @DanSingerman good answer For category and tags you should have a look at [Taxonomy](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy) and also [SimpleView](http://drupal.org/project/simpleviews) to get some less advanced user interface when building your views.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only displaying articles, you should go with Wordpress.  Most Drupalistas would probably recommend Wordpress over Drupal for this usage.

Comment: The reason that I didn't use Wordpress is that I didn't found a business portal like theme.

Comment: You shouldn't have a problem finding a theme like that.  Use Artisteer or spend a few bucks at rentacoder.  Themes, also, are one of the easiest and first things to learn about your CMS.  They're almost globally very simple.